# Why do it get parent.childElementCount as undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

I am teaching myself some Javascript and don't understand why Chrome console tells me this when I try it out at the Google homepage:

```
parent
> DOMWindow
parent.childNodes
> undefined
parent.frames[0].childElementCount
> undefined
parent.frames.length
> 1
parent.frames[0].name
> "wgjf"
parent.wgjf.childElementCount
> undefined
parent.frames[0].childElementCount
> undefined
parent.childElementCount
> undefined
```

I do notice that there are frames, and the parent has child nodes, so why all these undefined?

I would like to teach myself to the point that I can figure out how clicking on a username in the gmail chat window on the left opens up a chat window on the right - I should be able to trace the list of function calls that makes this happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

childNodes is a property of DOM-nodes, a window-object is not a DOM-Node.

Try:

```
parent //window-object
.document //document-object
.documentElement //root-node, usually <html>
.childNodes // usually <head> and <body>
```

like suggested by casablanca.

(should return 2 for a valid HTML-document)

Comment: Right, and specifically, the OP needs `parent.frames[0].document.documentElement.childElementCount`

Comment: Would this be the same reason why document.frames -> undefined (as frames can be property of a window which document is not?)

Comment: @PoorLuzer: yes, it's the same reason.